# SQL Comparing columns and calculating the difference

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle 11gR2

I have a table for example:

```
ProductName   |   Volume   |   Date
-------------------------------------------
ProdA         |   1000     |   11-Oct-2013
ProdA         |   2000     |   16-Oct-2013
ProdB         |   500      |   12-Oct-2013

ProdA         |   200      |   11-Nov-2013
ProdB         |   100      |   16-Nov-2013
ProdB         |   300      |   12-Nov-2013
```

What i want to do is total the volume for each product and then compare the volume across 2 months and have a calculated field working out the difference, so i would end up with:

```
ProductName   |   VolumeCurrentMonth   |   VolumePrevMonth   |   Difference
-------------------------------------------
ProdA         |   200                  |   3000              |    -2800
ProdB         |   400                  |   500               |    -100
```

My code is no where near the fulfilling the requirement but i'll post it anyway:

```
Select ProductName, sum(Volume), to_char(Date, 'Month') as Current_Month, to_char(run_date, 'Month') as PY_Month
from Sales
where Date is not null
group by ProductName, Date;
```

Comment: Yeah that returned what i needed pretty much, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a two-step appoarch - first, an inner query to group by products and months. Then, the outer query can handle the comparing with the previous month using the analytic `LAG` function:

```
SELECT productName, volume_sum AS curr_month_sum, 
       LAG(volume_sum) OVER (PARTITION BY productName ORDER BY month)
FROM   (SELECT    productName, trunc(theDate, 'MM-YYYY') AS month, SUM(volume) as volume_sum
        FROM      some_table
        GROUP BY  productName, trunc(theDate, 'MM-YYYY')
       )
```